# How do I serialize indirect relationships with querysets?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have built a Django REST application to serve as backend API For an iOS project. In my object model I use 'Subscription' to join 'User' objects with 'Workspace' objects. Here's a part of my models.py simplified:

```
class User(models.Model):
    # some property fields

class Workspace(models.Model):
    # some property fields

class Subscription(models.Model):
    # some property fields
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='subscriptions')
    workspace = models.ForeignKey(
        Workspace,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='subscriptions')
```

I have built class-based views for the objects so I can get a list of workspace objects with http GET from my iOS front end. For convenience reasons I want to include more than just the model fields, for example in the list of workspaces i want to include a list of subscribed users for every workspace object. I was advised to use SerializerMethodField() and querysets for serializing the field, but I don't know how to construct the queries. I've got this far:

```
class WorkspaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscribed_users = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Workspace
        fields = ('id', 'subscribed_users')

    def get_users(self, workspace):
        users = User.objects.filter(???)
        serializer = UserSerializer(instance=users, many=True)
        return serializer.data
```

Getting subscriptions related to the workspace is easy because they're directly related, but how do I get users that are subscribed to the workspace in question?

Answer (score 2):

The syntax I was looking for was double underscore, called [spanning](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships) in DRF. For example:

```
def get_users(self, workspace):
    users = User.objects.filter(subscription_set__workspace=workspace)
    serializer = UserSerializer(instance=users, many=True)
    return serializer.data
```